# Random failures in build pipelines when running dotnet-ef

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ef-core-3.1

As part of build I need to generate db migration script. I'm using Microsoft provided build agent

(only interesting part below)

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Install dotnet-ef
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        custom: 'tool'
        arguments: 'install dotnet-ef -g --version 5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Generate migrations sql script
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        custom: 'ef'
        arguments: 'migrations script --project Web/Dal --startup-project Web/WebApi --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --context EmailContext --no-build --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/emailcontext-migrations.sql --idempotent --verbose'
```

`dotnet-ef` installation seems to work fine:
`Tool 'dotnet-ef' (version '5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4') was successfully installed.`

but it still fails from time to time with (more often recently) :

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ef migrations script --project Web/Dal --startup-project Web/WebApi --configuration Release --context EmailContext --no-build --output D:\a\1\a/emailcontext-migrations.sql --idempotent --verbose
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
```

Is there a problem with my build pipeline configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If it fails from time to time I would rather say that this can be an issue with preview version.

Please add an next step after installing to list all globally installed tools:

```
dotnet tool list -g
```

You may also show us a log of installing tool for case when your pipeline doesn't work. To verify if you have this:

[image]

(We simply don't know it, since we can't check your logs).

And if it still happens I would encourage you to create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore).

Comment: Installation always succeeds. I pasted the log. There was the same issue when we were using latest stable version of ef tools.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this is an intermittent issue. So your pipeline configuration could be **correct**.

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.

This issue seems to be related to the dotnet-ef package installed.

As Krzysztof Madej's suggestion, this package version could cause this issue.

You could try to use the latest version: `5.0.0-rc.1.20451.13` or latest stable version: `3.1.8`.

Here is [a GitHub ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12921) with the same issue( Can't find the file after global installing dotnet-ef). You could follow it and check the update.

On the other hand,  you could try to use the `Command Line Task` to install the dotnet-ef.

For example:

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef  --version xxxx'
```

Comment: I had the same issue with 3.1 * family so it doesn't seem version related.

Comment: I use 3.1.2 on production for long time without any issue. Can you try this version?